# Alterar cor do texto do botão ao clicar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Gostaria de saber como faço pra alterar a cor do texto da escrita do botão quando eu clico nele, eu quero que eu clique no botão e ele saia da cor dourada e fique na cor branca até eu clicar novamente nele, mas o que eu consegui até agora é que ele mude de cor apenas quando o mouse fica em cima. Segue abaixo código css e html que eu fiz até o momento:
css:

```
#login{
        @extend .table;
        cursor:pointer;
        position:relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 79px;

        #centralizar_menu{
            @extend .row;
            text-align: center;
            height: 4.8em;}

        &:hover{
            #texto_cliente #titulo{
                display: block!Important;
                @extend .fonte_branca_13;
            }
            background-color: $dourado;
        }

        #texto_cliente{
            width: 100%;
            height: 1.5em;
            padding: 0.5em 0em;

            #titulo{
                @extend .fonte_dourado_13;
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="login">
    <div id="centralizar_menu">
        <div class="middle">
            <div id="texto_cliente">
                <div id="titulo">Login</div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: você só quer com css? ou quer usar com jquery?

Comment: De preferência apenas com css

Comment: Já tentou usar com a pseudo-classe  ":active" ? ali em cima você usou o hover, que é quando você passa o cursor do mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue opção de botão: OBS: Utilizando Sass:

```
.botao_licitacao {
    background: #003366;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: em(45);
    font-weight: bold;
    &:hover{
        background: #072440;
    }
    span{
        color: #fff;
    }
    p{
        color: #fff !important;
        @extend .fonte_light;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        text-shadow: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
    &:hover{
        background: #072440;
    }
    &:hover{
        background: #072440;
    }
    &:visited{
        background: #072440;
    }
}
```

Comment: Caso não utilize sass é só criar a classe com a propriedade ao lado, exemplo: .botao_licitacao p{}

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar a pseudo classe

```
&:active{
   //aqui vem como você quer que ele fique quando for clicado
}
```

do mesmo modo que você usou a hover

Comment: eu estou usando &:hover, já tentei com &:active, e ele permanece dourado

Comment: quer dizer, ele fica branco apenas quando eu seguro o botão do mouse clicado

Comment: como que eu faria com jQuery?

Comment: @BernardoKowacic, me mostre como ficou o código com &:active. Provavelmente, o que você quer somente com javascript/jquery

Comment: &:active{
                #texto_cliente #titulo{
                    display: block!Important;
                    @extend .fonte_branca_13;
                }
                background-color: $dourado;
            }

Comment: O problema dessa resposta é que ele não vai criar um toggle da classe, vai apenas manter a mudança de cor enquanto o `clique` for mantido. Após soltar, ele irá se perder.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, então como você acha que poderia ser feito?

Comment: Se você já está utilizando jQuery, dê uma olhada na resposta abaixo, do Pedro Camara Junior, ela deve funcionar como você deseja.

Comment: na realidade não estou usando nenhum jquery nesse site

Answer (score 1):

Eu usaria jQuery para isso;

```
var $divLogin = $("#login");
$divLogin.click(function(){
if ($divLogin.hasClass("dourado"))
    $divLogin.addClass("branco").removeClass("dourado");
else
    $divLogin.addClass("dourado").removeClass("branco");
});
```

Na tua div adicione inicialmente a classe que desejar

```
<div id="login" class="dourado">Login</div>
```

E por fim, defina o css para cada classe

```
.dourado {
    color: yellow;
}

.branco {
    color: white;
}
```

Basicamente o que é feito é verificar qual classe está ativa na div e trocá-la para a outra.

Answer (score 0):

Meu problema foi igual, mas simples de resolver:

```
btn{
/*defini o botão*/
}

btn:hover{
/*Como ele vai ficar ao passar o mouse, ou para o mouse encima*/
}

btn:focus{
/*aqui está a resolução aqui define a cor que o botão deve receber depois de clicar*/
}
```